# How can I solve spamassassin DKIM timeout request?

Tags: mail-server, dkim, spamassassin

I have a mail server runs CentOS 7 with Exim + Dovecot + Spamassassin v3.4.0, and VestaCP.
Everything works fine except too long spamassassin check. It takes 10-11 seconds.

At the spamassassin debug log I see that the problem with DNS query for DKIM record (1st log line) and it terminates with 10 seconds timeout (3rd log line). And it fails DKIM test.

```
Sun Jul 14 14:47:12 2019 [94687] dbg: dkim: performing public key lookup and signature verification
Sun Jul 14 14:47:22 2019 [94687] dbg: dkim: DKIM, i=@yandex.ru, d=yandex.ru, s=mail, a=rsa-sha256, c=relaxed/relaxed, invalid, matches author domain
Sun Jul 14 14:47:22 2019 [94687] dbg: dkim: signature verification result: INVALID (PUBLIC KEY: DNS QUERY TIMEOUT FOR MAIL._DOMAINKEY.YANDEX.RU)
Sun Jul 14 14:47:22 2019 [94687] dbg: dkim: adsp: performing lookup on _adsp._domainkey.yandex.ru
Sun Jul 14 14:47:22 2019 [94687] dbg: dkim: adsp result: U/unknown (dns: unknown), author domain 'yandex.ru'
Sun Jul 14 14:47:22 2019 [94687] dbg: spf: checking to see if the message has a Received-SPF header that we can use
Sun Jul 14 14:47:22 2019 [94687] dbg: spf: checking HELO (helo=forward400j.mail.yandex.net, ip=5.45.198.245)
Sun Jul 14 14:47:22 2019 [94687] dbg: dns: bgsend,  DNS servers: [8.8.8.8]:53, [8.8.4.4]:53
Sun Jul 14 14:47:22 2019 [94687] dbg: dns: attempt 1/2, trying connect/sendto to [8.8.8.8]:53
Sun Jul 14 14:47:22 2019 [94687] dbg: dns: providing a callback for id: 49973/IN/SPF/forward400j.mail.yandex.net
Sun Jul 14 14:47:22 2019 [94687] dbg: dns: dns reply 690 is OK, 4 answer records
Sun Jul 14 14:47:22 2019 [94687] dbg: async: calling callback on key dns:A:yandex.ru
Sun Jul 14 14:47:22 2019 [94687] dbg: dns: hit <dns:yandex.ru> 5.255.255.5
Sun Jul 14 14:47:22 2019 [94687] dbg: dns: hit <dns:yandex.ru> 77.88.55.50
Sun Jul 14 14:47:22 2019 [94687] dbg: dns: hit <dns:yandex.ru> 77.88.55.88
Sun Jul 14 14:47:22 2019 [94687] dbg: dns: hit <dns:yandex.ru> 5.255.255.88
```

If I run special check with `spamassassin -t -D dkim` **at the same email** then eveything works fast and DKIM passing test.

```
# spamassassin -t -D dkim < /home/admin/mail/domain/user/cur/messageId
Jul 14 20:46:49.922 [24398] dbg: dkim: using Mail::DKIM version 0.39
Jul 14 20:46:49.923 [24398] dbg: dkim: performing public key lookup and signature verification
Jul 14 20:46:49.962 [24398] dbg: dkim: DKIM, i=@yandex.ru, d=yandex.ru, s=mail, a=rsa-sha256, c=relaxed/relaxed, pass, matches author domain
Jul 14 20:46:49.962 [24398] dbg: dkim: signature verification result: PASS
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with install local DNS resolver instead of using Google DNS.